# How can I define probabilities in my randscr function (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, probability

I am trying to conduct an experiment with two conditions, which should be displayed with a certain probability. In this case "Trial_p" should be presented in 2/3 of the cases and "Trial_c" in 1/3. When I run the experiment I do get a quite random sequence, but the probabilities are not as I defined them! Can anyone help?

```
  Trial_p = [0 4 1 2]; % trial with percept
  td1 = [0 1 0.5 2];
  Trial_c = [0 4 3]; % control trial
  td2 = [0 1 2];

  total_ntrials = 9; % 120 trials

  prob1 = 1/3*2; %0.66
  prob2 = 1/3*1; %0.33

  my_sequence = [];
  my_duration = [];

 randomized_seq = randsrc(1,total_ntrials,[1,2; prob1,prob2]); % randomize trialtypes 
  %x = rand(1)*(10-5) + 5;
   for i = 1:length(randomized_seq)
       if randomized_seq(i) == 1
           td1(1) = floor(rand(1)*(5-1)+1);    %(30-20) + 20);
           my_sequence = cat(2, my_sequence, Trial_p);
           my_duration = cat(2, my_duration, td1);
       elseif randomized_seq(i) == 2
           td2(1) = floor(rand(1)*(10-5) + 5);
           my_sequence = cat(2, my_sequence, Trial_c);
           my_duration = cat(2, my_duration, td2);
       end
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *observed* proportions will naturally deviate from the *expected* probabilities unless the number of observations is very high ([law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)). Try generating a large number of values and check:

```
>> prob1 = 2/3;
>> prob2 = 1/3;
>> randomized_seq = randsrc(1,1e6,[1,2; prob1,prob2]);
>> mean(randomized_seq==1)
>> mean(randomized_seq==2)
```

gives

```
ans =
   0.666610000000000
ans =
   0.333390000000000
```

If you want an *exact proportion*, say 80 and 40 of each case:

```
randomized_seq = repelem([1 2], [40 80]); % generate exact number of cases
randomized_seq = randomized_seq(randperm(numel(randomized_seq))); % random shuffle
```